# The difference in results when calculating distance with Python haver and R distHaversine

Tags: python, r, haversine, geosphere

When calculating the distance between two locations with Python and R, I get different results. Python seems to be accurate

#### Python

```
import haversine as hs
hs.haversine((41.8777, -87.6353), (41.8915, -87.6268))        # 1.688136 km
hs.haversine((28.426846, 77.088834), (28.394231, 77.050308))  # 5.229712 km
```

#### R

```
library(geosphere)
distHaversine(c(41.8777, -87.6353), c(41.8915, -87.6268))     # 948.3439 meters
distHaversine(c(28.426846,77.088834), c(28.394231,77.050308)) # 4364.968 meters
```

Why the calculations in R is different?

Comment: Why do you say Python is more accurate? What are you comparing with?

Comment: Verify that the coordinates are in the correct order. I believe geosphere requires longitude first then latitude.  Does this answer your question? [Distance between points in GPX file becomes too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252840/distance-between-points-in-gpx-file-becomes-too-large)

Comment: Thank you Dave2e, it works. longitude comes first. @Sam Rogers. tried several online calculators.